# How can I test rails controller actions call proper methods with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Given this,

```
class SomeController < AbstractDocumentsController
  def create
    foo_method(params)
    bar_method
  end
end
```

How can I test `foo_method` and `bar_method` is called when `create` action is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use mocks for this. 
Example with rspec-mocks [Github docs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class)

For you code sample you can use something like this, I think
expect_any_instance_of(SomeController).to receive(:foo_method)